# React add unmounted component to the array

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to create multiple components for future rendering adding tham to the array like this:

```
widgets.push(<TextWidget fieldData={fieldData} correctionFactor={correctionFactor} />);
```

but in my component I'm getting

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'FieldData' of undefined

```
class TextWidget extends Component {
    FieldData = null;
    CorrectionFactor = null;

    state = {
        FieldData: null, 
        CorrectionFactor: null
    }

    constructor(props) {
        this.FieldData = props.fieldData;
        this.CorrectionFactor = props.correctionFactor || 1;        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.FieldData = this.FieldData;
        this.state.CorrectionFactor = this.CorrectionFactor;
    }
....
```

if i do smth like `this.state.FieldData = props.FieldData;` in a constructor then react is complaining about being unable to set state of unmounted component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you forgot call `super()` inside your constructor as a first line

```
super(props);
```

According to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> You should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You're committing two mistakes.

- **First:** You should call the `super(props)` before manipulating the props, then use the `this.props.FieldData`, and you could do it even in the `constructor()`, when defining the state, like:

  ```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          FieldData: this.props.FieldData,
          CorrectionFactor: this.props.CorrectionFactor || 1
      };
  }
  ```
- **Second:** You shouldn't set state like you did:

  ```
  this.state.FieldData = this.FieldData;
  ```

You should use the `this.setState()`(read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)), like below:

```
this.setState({
   FieldData: this.props.FieldData,
   CorrectionFactor: this.props.CorrectionFactor
});
```